# How to slice and extend a 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of size `nxm`. I want the number of columns to be limited to `k` and rest of the columns to be extended in new rows. Following is the scenario -

Initial array: `nxm`

Final array: `pxk`

where `p = (m/k)*n`

Eg. `n = 2, m = 6, k = 2`

Initial array:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,],
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Final array:

```
[[1, 2],
[7, 8],
[3, 4],
[9, 10],
[5, 6],
[11, 12]]
```

I tried using `reshape` but not getting the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it

```
q=array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,],
         [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]])
r=q.T.reshape(-1,2,2)
s=r.swapaxes(1,2)
t=s.reshape(-1,2)
```

as a one liner,

```
q.T.reshape(-1,2,2).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1,2)

array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 9, 10],
       [ 5,  6],
       [11, 12]])
```

EDIT: for the general case, use

```
q=arange(1,1+n*m).reshape(n,m) #example input
r=q.T.reshape(-1,k,n)
s=r.swapaxes(1,2)
t=s.reshape(-1,k)
```

one liner is:

```
q.T.reshape(-1,k,n).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1,k)
```

example for `n=3,m=12,k=4`

```
q=array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
         [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
         [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]])
```

result is

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [13, 14, 15, 16],
       [25, 26, 27, 28],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [17, 18, 19, 20],
       [29, 30, 31, 32],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [21, 22, 23, 24],
       [33, 34, 35, 36]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`numpy.vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) and [`numpy.hsplit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hsplit.html):

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,],
              [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]])
n, m, k = 2, 6, 2
np.vstack(np.hsplit(a, m/k))
```

result array:

```
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 9, 10],
       [ 5,  6],
       [11, 12]])
```

**UPDATE** As [flebool commented](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22143352/2225682?noredirect=1#comment33608900_22143388), above code is very slow, because `hsplit` returns a python list, and then `vstack` reconstructs the final array from a list of arrays.

Here's alternative solution that is much faster.

```
a.reshape(-1, m/k, k).transpose(1, 0, 2).reshape(-1, k)
```

or

```
a.reshape(-1, m/k, k).swapaxes(0, 1).reshape(-1, k)
```

Comment: +1. Notice however that `hsplit` returns a python list, and then `vstack` reconstructs the final array from a list of arrays. This is much slower.

Comment: @flebool, Thank you for the information. +1 your answer.

Comment: Well.. You first posted a wrong answer, then deleted it. Then posted another wrong answer, and deleted it. Finally, you're basically copying my answer. I am downvoting, this is not fair IMHO. sorry.

Comment: @flebool, I didn't copy your answer.

Comment: @flebool, BTW, I deleted only once.

Comment: @flebool, I agree that my very first deleted answer was totally wrong. The second answer is slow, but is not wrong. The updated answer is different from yours.

Comment: clicking edit I see 2 deleted posts, boh. I don't comment the bit about copying, others will decide, there are many, many ways of using transpose/swapaxes to obtain a new view of the array, but it's the same trick in the end. I won't comment further.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48886/discussion-between-falsetru-and-flebool)